# how to call a template using an key via XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I almost had this resolved then found out that the coverage-ref was to a key attribute in a corresponding coverage element .

Xpath would look like

/message/person-info/claim-list/claim/

```
<coverage-ref>4</coverage-ref>
```

/message/person-info/coverage-list/

```
<coverage key="4" id="23" >
...
</coverage>
```

snippet of current XSL

```
<xsl:template match="claim" mode="fact">
    <ClaimFact>
        <coverage>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="./coverage-ref">
                    <!-- 
                    COVERAGE-<xsl:value-of select="util:ifNull(./coverage-ref, '0')"/>
                    -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="coverage-ref">
                            <xsl:with-param name="coverage-ref" select="./coverage-ref" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="./../../../coverage/@id">COVERAGE-<xsl:value-of select="./../../../coverage/@id"/></xsl:when>                       
                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>UNKNOWNCOVERAGE</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </coverage>     
    </ClaimFact>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="coverage|coverage-ref" >
<xsl:param name="coverage-ref" />
<xsl:variable name="coverage" 
        select="/person-info/coverage-list/coverage[@key = $coverage-ref]" />   
    <CoverageDimension>
        <mycoverageref><xsl:value-of select="$coverage" /></mycoverageref>
...

    </CoverageDimension>
</xsl:template>
```

The error I am getting

```
Error at xsl:call-template on line 1845 column 51 of personinfo.xsl:
  XTSE0650: No template exists named coverage-ref
```

The existing as commented out would put the coverage-ref into the mycoverageref.

What I am trying to do with the xsl:call-template, xsl:param, and xsl:variable is to either 1) set the mycoverageref to the @id of the  element rather than than the @key.

2) Better would be to replace the value 4 to 23, the existing apply-templates should then work on the CoverageDimension.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to call a named template "template-ref"

```
<xsl:call-template name="coverage-ref">
   <xsl:with-param name="coverage-ref" select="./coverage-ref" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

But there is no such template in your XSLT. You only have a template that matches an **coverage-ref** element

```
<xsl:template match="coverage|coverage-ref">
```

Thich is not the same thing as a named template.

It is possible you meant to do this...

```
<xsl:template match="coverage" name="coverage-ref">
```

This would be both a matching template, and a named template. Alternatively, you could change your original **xsl:call-template** to an **xsl:apply-templates** here

```
<xsl:apply-template select="coverage-ref">
    <xsl:with-param name="coverage-ref" select="./coverage-ref" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

You wouldn't really need to pass the parameter in this though. The matching template could just get the value of the element directly.

```
<xsl:template match="coverage-ref" >
    <xsl:variable name="coverage" select="/person-info/coverage-list/coverage[@key = .]" />
```

But in any case, you talk about 'keys', but you are not actually using a 'proper' key. In particular an **xsl:key**. And this is just the sort of thing you need in this situation. You want to look up **coverage** elements by their **key** attribute? Then just define a key like so

```
<xsl:key name="coverageLookup" match="coverage" use="@key" />
```

Then to look up the coverage element, just do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('coverageLookup', $coverage-ref)/@id" />
```

Or, if you were using a matched template, it would look like this

```
<xsl:template match="coverage-ref" >
   <CoverageDimension>
      <mycoverageref><xsl:value-of select="key('coverageLookup', .)/@id" /></mycoverageref>
      ...
   </CoverageDimension>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I used part of your solution and will post what I did in an answer. The current xsl has no keys or keylookups defined. We may want to go this route for future releases, but this will entail an entire rewrite of the existing xsl.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and many thanks to @Tim-C . We will have to consider keyLookups for future editions, but this works for the current xml. Using the variable `$coverpath` to match the `coverage/@key` with the `coverage-ref/text()` value makes this work.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="20" 
...
<xsl:template match="person-info">
    <PersonDimension>
    ...
    </PersonDimension>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="coverage-list/coverage" />         
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//claim-list/claim" mode="fact" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="claim" mode="fact">
    <xsl:variable name="coveragepath" 
        select="/message/person-info/coverage-list/coverage[@key = current()/coverage-ref/text()]" />

    <ClaimFact>
...
        <coverage>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$coveragepath/@id">                     
                        COVERAGE-<xsl:value-of select="$coveragepath/@id"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="./../../../coverage/@id">COVERAGE-<xsl:value-of select="./../../../coverage/@id"/></xsl:when>                       
                    <xsl:otherwise>UNKNOWNCOVERAGE</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </coverage> 
    </ClaimFact>

</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="coverage" >
<CoverageDimension>
        <jaxbId>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@id">COVERAGE-<xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>UNKNOWNCOVERAGE</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </jaxbId>
    </CoverageDimension>
</xsl:template>
```